# Dynamic Array Dimensions

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamic

I'm in need of a multidimensional array such that the number and size of the dimensions are specified at runtime. For example, I might end up with a

```
double[,] array;
```

or I might end up with a

```
double[,,,] array;
```

but I wont know until runtime.

Comment: Have you seen the answers to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934453/c-sharp-dynamic-multidimensional-array

Comment: What variable type will you be storing this unknown-dimensioned array in?

Comment: You could use a List...
'private List mylist;'

Comment: What do you need this for? You can easily create one using [`Array.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dfs8044k) but using it will be painful and there may be a better solution.

Comment: I'm just making a simple Q-learning agent. I want to use a multidimensional array to represent the state table. I'm actually almost finished implementing it with Array.CreateInstance as of now. It's a super light-weight RL technique, and multidimensional arrays fit the problem like a glove.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Array.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dfs8044k) to build this array, but you can't have it strongly typed in code.  Instead, you will need to use [`Array.Rank`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.array.rank), [`Array.GetLowerBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.array.getlowerbound), and [`Array.GetUpperBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.array.getupperbound) to work with the array.

Comment: Beautiful. Array.CreateInstance is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!