# best practice of two-dimension dynamic array creation and sort

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, dynamic

target:

1. dynamic array with size [N][2] ( or [N,2] ) (3 elements per row, all elements is *string*)
2. Sort array by third row

   ---

At this moment I have declared array like this:

```
List<List<string>> testsNamesList = new List<List<string>>();
```

and adding of new element like this:

```
testsNamesArray.Add(new List<string>());
testsNamesArray[TestItemNumber].Add("string_1");
testsNamesArray[TestItemNumber].Add("string_2");
testsNamesArray[TestItemNumber].Add("422");
```

---

Question 1: I'm not sure, is this the best practice of two-dimension dynamic array creation?

Question 2: How can I sort this array by third item of row?

Comment: Do you really neeed dynamic sizes in both directions, or columns count is constant?

Comment: Are you sure, you want a `List<List<string>>` and not an `IDictionary<int, Tuple<string, string, string>>` or some even more appropriate structure?

Comment: @VladimirMezentsev : 3 elements per row; So dynamic in one direction.

Comment: There's a big difference between a List that you use here and an Array in C#, this piece of code has nothing to do with arrays. A two-dimensional array would look like string[,].

Comment: @Corak no, I'm not sure =) And thats the reason why I'm ask this question. Is IDictionary easier to sort by third item?

Comment: @ThomasLindvall As in C# no ability to declare array with DYNAMIC size, I think the only choice is to use list as array for save data =) If you know how to create really dynamic "array"(not List or something else) -- tell me =)

Comment: Well, a dictionary has quick access by key, which you seem to need with `testsNamesArray[TestItemNumber]`. The values of a dictionary can then be easily sorted like any other `IEnumerable<T>` with `theDictionary.Values.OrderBy(item => item.Item2)` for example. - Note, that this doesn't *actually* change the order, but produces an ordered output.

Comment: Btw. a `List<T>` is "just" a wrapper around `T[]` with all the pain of dynamic growing and other inconveniencies taken care of.

Comment: @Andrew http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934453/c-sharp-dynamic-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create class *MyRow* containing 3 strings(*First*,*Second* and *Third*) Maybe you need other types(as by now you have third column as int) and then use

```
List<MyRow> mycollection;
```

as your collection. After that you can use Linq to get sorted data by

```
var ordered=mycollection.OrderBy(x=>x.Third);
```

Comment: Yes, creating a specific class to represent the row is probably the best way to go.